# Como aproveitar armazenamento em cache do navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, htaccess, seo, blogger

Eu li e reli várias vezes sobre este assunto mas nunca entendo como algo que eu faço no meu computador vai fazer o site ficar mais rápido no computador de terceiros...

Sem contar que ao fazer tais modificações no meu computador eu terei que fazer isto toda vez em que logar em um IP diferente?

Eu simplesmente não entendo como funciona! De qualquer forma como eu devo fazer isso? Qual a forma mais fácil de se fazer isso?

Sem contar que eu estou querendo deixar um site, que não é meu, mais rápido, no momento eu tenho acesso ao código e posso modifica-lo, mas depois não terei, e a dona do site não sabe mexer nestas coisas, as informações ditas no pagespeed diz que eu preciso fazer modificações de tempo em tempo, mas não há nenhuma forma deu fazer isso  por dois anos ou pelo menos um ano... ?

Trata-se de um blogger!

Comment: Você pode começar fazendo uma faxina no seu CSS, das classes que não são usadas mas que são importadas pelo site. http://tableless.com.br/fazendo-uma-faxina-seu-css/ . Também caso o site carregue muitas imagens, é uma boa você compactar tais imagens para formatos mais leves, melhorando assim o carregamento. Uma dica de leitura: http://tableless.com.br/acelere-o-carregamento-de-suas-paginas/ .

Comment: Então em não preciso modificar nada no .htacess do meu computador?  @Matheus Irei lê e modificar o css e as imagens e vê se dá uma melhorada. ;)